# Executing python file from Java code giving errors

Tags: jython, jython-2.7

I am executing python scripts from Java using the jython library(jython-standalone-2.7-b3). My only intention is to be able to trigger and execute python script files from my java code. I was able to do this properly writing standalone main classes and things went well. Now I put the same code inside my application(within my app server), and now for the same script i get errors at each and every stage. It says a few module cannot be found etc. But adding more to my confusion the same code and script executes just fine when i try it again from the main class. Is there anything that the running environment has to inject to make this run..

The code snippet used

```
    public void executeScript(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    final PythonInterpreter inter = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
    Writer writer = null;
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
    inter.setOut(writer);
    inter.execfile(inputFile);
}
```

The exception that i get is

```
File "/data/WorkArea/anoj/APPNEW/com.anoj.commons.core/lib/jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar/Lib/posixpath.py", line 392, in normpath
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

```
at org.python.core.Py.AttributeError(Py.java:177)
at org.python.core.PyObject.noAttributeError(PyObject.java:946)
at org.python.core.PyObject.__getattr__(PyObject.java:941)
at posixpath$py.normpath$27(/data/WorkArea/anoj/APPNEW/com.anoj.commons.core/lib/jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar/Lib/posixpath.py:412)
at posixpath$py.call_function(/data/WorkArea/anoj/APPNEW/com.anoj.commons.core/lib/jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar/Lib/posixpath.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:166)
at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:137)
at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:347)
at sysconfig$py.f$0(/data/WorkArea/anoj/APPNEW/com.anoj.commons.core/lib/jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar/Lib/sysconfig.py:712)
at sysconfig$py.call_function(/data/WorkArea/anoj/APPNEW/com.anoj.commons.core/lib/jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar/Lib/sysconfig.py)
at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:166)
at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:393)
at org.python.core.util.importer.importer_load_module(importer.java:109)
at org.python.modules.zipimport.zipimporter.zipimporter_load_module(zipimporter.java:161)
at org.python.modules.zipimport.zipimporter$zipimporter_load_module_exposer.__call__(Unknown Source)
at org.python.core.PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.__call__(PyBuiltinMethodNarrow.java:47)
at org.python.core.imp.loadFromLoader(imp.java:520)
at org.python.core.imp.loadFromLoader(imp.java:520)
```

Please help..

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to "trigger and execute python script files from [your] Java code"?  Can we see the code snippet?  Can we see the actual errors?

Comment: public void executeScript(String inputFile, String outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
  final PythonInterpreter inter = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
  Writer writer = null;
  writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
  inter.setOut(writer);
  inter.execfile(inputFile);
 }


................The inputFile param is the location of the python that i need to execute. The outputFile is only to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: The error that i get is ..... File "/data/WorkArea/anoj/APPNEW/com.anoj.commons.core/lib/jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar/Lib/posixpath.py", line 392, in normpath
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' 
 at org.python.core.Py.AttributeError(Py.java:177)
 at org.python.core.PyObject.noAttributeError(PyObject.java:946)
 at org.python.core.PyObject.__getattr__(PyObject.java:941)
 at posixpath$py.normpath$27(/data/WorkArea/anoj/APPNEW/com.anoj.commons.core/lib/jython-standalone-2.7-b3.jar/Lib/posixpath.py:412) ...

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional information.

Comment: This is strange, because your own program does not appear to be anywhere on the stack.  Did you provide the whole stack trace?  I created my own program very much like yours and it worked fine.